# Raspberry Pi SpringBoot Issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, raspberry-pi

I have recently began using the Raspberry Pi 2 to run basic Java applications to activate the GPIO's and turn on LEDs. I want to expand on what I have already learned, but I've run into an issue, no requests are activating the GPIO's, despite returning a String to the browser which I am issuing these commands from. I have gotten multiple projects to work, but all of a sudden, no GPIO's would activate, and a message was displayed from Pi that I had not seen before, this is what the putty displayed:

---

:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.0.RELEASE)

2015-12-01 07:34:25.129  INFO 2681 --- [           main] com.Ras.mm.Application                                                                                                                               : Starting Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on raspberrypi with PID 2681 (/home/pi/la                                                                                                            st/PiLedTesbet/target/mm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /home/pi/last/PiLedTesbet)
2015-12-01 07:34:25.154  INFO 2681 --- [           main] com.Ras.mm.Application                                                                                                                               : No profiles are active
2015-12-01 07:34:25.625  INFO 2681 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicatio                                                                                                            nContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedW                                                                                                            ebApplicationContext@4af5ff: startup date [Tue Dec 01 07:34:25 UTC 2015]; root of context                                                                                                             hierarchy
2015-12-01 07:34:31.892  INFO 2681 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFac                                                                                                            tory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different de                                                                                                            finition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; aut                                                                                                            owireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=or                                                                                                            g.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewCon                                                                                                            figuration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodNam                                                                                                            e=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/                                                                                                            ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class                                                                                                             [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autow                                                                                                            ireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.                                                                                                            web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameVie                                                                                                            wResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resou                                                                                                            rce [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigu                                                                                                            rationAdapter.class]]
2015-12-01 07:34:37.043  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletC                                                                                                            ontainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9191 (http)
2015-12-01 07:34:37.139  INFO 2681 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardS                                                                                                            ervice   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-12-01 07:34:37.148  INFO 2681 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.Standar                                                                                                            dEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
2015-12-01 07:34:37.811  INFO 2681 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[                                                                                                            /]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-12-01 07:34:37.813  INFO 2681 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader                                                                                                                        : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12210 ms
2015-12-01 07:34:40.660  INFO 2681 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBea                                                                                                            n        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-12-01 07:34:40.703  INFO 2681 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrat                                                                                                            ionBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-01 07:34:40.706  INFO 2681 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrat                                                                                                            ionBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-01 07:34:40.707  INFO 2681 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrat                                                                                                            ionBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-01 07:34:40.708  INFO 2681 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrat                                                                                                            ionBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-01 07:34:42.932  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.Annot                                                                                                            ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4af5ff: startup date [Tue Dec 01 07:34:25 UTC 20                                                                                                            15]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-01 07:34:43.668  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/off]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Ras.mm.controller.LedContro                                                                                                            ller.off()
2015-12-01 07:34:43.675  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/on]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Ras.mm.controller.LedControl                                                                                                            ler.on()
2015-12-01 07:34:43.677  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/toggle]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Ras.mm.controller.LedCon                                                                                                            troller.light()
2015-12-01 07:34:43.678  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/pulse]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Ras.mm.controller.LedCont                                                                                                            roller.pulse()
2015-12-01 07:34:43.680  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/blink]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Ras.mm.controller.LedCont                                                                                                            roller.blink()
2015-12-01 07:34:43.682  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/seiz50]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Ras.mm.controller.LedCon                                                                                                            troller.seiz()
2015-12-01 07:34:43.684  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/seiz25]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Ras.mm.controller.LedCon                                                                                                            troller.seiz1()
2015-12-01 07:34:43.685  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Ras.mm.controller.LedControlle                                                                                                            r.hi()
2015-12-01 07:34:43.702  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.s                                                                                                            ervlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error                                                                                                            Html(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-12-01 07:34:43.704  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandle                                                                                                            rMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.B                                                                                                            asicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-12-01 07:34:44.095  INFO 2681 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandler                                                                                                            Mapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.                                                                                                            web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-01 07:34:44.096  INFO 2681 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandler                                                                                                            Mapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.serv                                                                                                            let.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-01 07:34:44.544  INFO 2681 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandler                                                                                                            Mapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframew                                                                                                            ork.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-01 07:34:46.054  INFO 2681 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporte                                                                                                            r        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-12-01 07:34:46.576  INFO 2681 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletC                                                                                                            ontainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9191 (http)
2015-12-01 07:34:46.601  INFO 2681 --- [           main] com.Ras.mm.Application                                                                                                                               : Started Application in 24.079 seconds (JVM running for 26.878)
2015-12-01 07:34:58.950  INFO 2681 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[                                                                                                            /]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-12-01 07:34:58.952  INFO 2681 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServle                                                                                                            t        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-12-01 07:34:59.099  INFO 2681 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServle                                                                                                            t        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 146 ms

### ^C2015-12-01 07:38:14.363  INFO 2681 --- [       Thread-3] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4af5ff: startup date [Tue Dec 01 07:34:25 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy 2015-12-01 07:38:14.373  INFO 2681 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

I've never seen the "Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown" message displayed before, if anyone has anyone knows how to help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The logmessage you highlighted is a standard message issued by Tomcat *when shutting down* (stopping the monitoring jmx service). What you want to find out is *why is it shutting down*. For that we would need the logmessages before these lines.

Comment: Not sure where the output is coming from here, but it looks like you hit Ctrl-C (immediately before the time in the log message you highlighted at the end), which has shut down the Spring Boot application, hence the message you're seeing, as Gergely Bacso says. I fear that your problem lies elsewhere...